# discord.js v13 | can't get targeted user's infos

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

i'm using discord.js version **13.1.0** with node.js version **16.7.0**, i writed this code to show me user's info in a embed, but the problem is it only shows me my infos.

I tried also this `guildMember.user` instead of `user` but it can't execute the command it shows me in the console `TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined`.

Here's the command's code:

```
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('info')
        .setDescription('Get info about a user or a server!')
        .addSubcommand(subcommand =>
            subcommand
                .setName('user')
                .setDescription('Info about a user')
                .addUserOption(option => option.setName('target').setDescription('The user'))),
    async userInfo = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#0099ff')
                .setTitle('Some title')
                .setAuthor('Some name', interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                .setDescription('Some description here')
                .setThumbnail(interaction.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                .addFields(
                    { name: 'Hello', value: 'Hello' },
                    { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
                    { name: 'ID', value: interaction.user.id, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Username', value: interaction.user.tag, inline: true },
                )
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png');
    if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === 'user') {
            const user = interaction.options.getUser('target');
            if (user) {
            await interaction.reply({ embeds: [userInfo] });
   };
};
```

Comment: do you have the privileged intents enabled in your bot?

Comment: Where is `interaction` defined?

Comment: This code is not even valid javascript... The `SlashCommandBuilder` builds the metadata for your command, and you should handle interactions in a function, or an `interactionCreate` listener.

Comment: @G-Force yeah i writed `const client = new Client({ intents:[Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });` in the main file of my bot (index.js).

Comment: @MrMythical in the index.js file i didn't make an event handler yet, look! the code is working i said the problem was the bot was returning only my infos even if i targeted someone to get his infos, hope you can see my answer below

Comment: @theusaf i didn't put the whole code to make my question easy to be readed.

Answer (score 0):

anyway the problem was it was an `interaction` before `user.'property or method'`, when you put `interaction` before the class `user` you only specify the user who commanded the bot in discord by using slashcommands, when you remove it you specify the targeted user. I hope you can understand this is a exemple for you:

```
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('user-tag')
    .setDescription('show a user\'s tag')
    .addUserOption(option => option.setName('target').setDescription('to show the targeted user\'s tag')),

async execute(interaction) {
    const user = interaction.options.getUser('target');
    if (user) {
        //to show targeted user's tag
        return interaction.reply(`the user\'s tag :${user.tag}`);
    } else {
        //to show your tag if you were the commander
        return interaction.reply(`the user\'s tag :${interaction.user.tag}`);
    }
```

if you have any other inforamtions about `interaction` you can put the source ofthe informations or you can tell us in the commants.